# Bringing a time series to the front in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

I have a line chart with many time series, nearly 400. Inevitably, some of those end up in the background. I am experimenting with code to highlight a time series in blue and bring it in the front when the mouse hovers over it. The color change works, but bringing the series to the foreground doesn't.

Here is a code fragment that reproduces the problem:

```
function mouseOverCallback(event, series) {
    series.graph.attr('stroke', 'steelblue')
  series.graph.toFront()
}

function mouseOutCallback(event, series) {
    series.graph.attr('stroke', 'lightgray')
}

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            stickyTracking: false,
            events: {
                mouseOver: function (e) {
                    mouseOverCallback(e, this)
                },
                mouseOut: function (e) {
                    mouseOutCallback(e, this)
                }
            }
        }
    },

    series: [
      {
          data: [48.85, 60.45, 115.44, 108.24, 134.0, 156.0, 155.6, 128.5, 206.4, 164.1, 55.6, 94.4],
          color: 'lightgray'
      },
      {
          data: [49.9, 61.5, 116.4, 109.2, 134.0, 156.0, 105.6, 108.5, 206.4, 164.1, 55.6, 94.4],
          color: 'lightgray'
      }
    ]
});
```

I [created a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/basiliosz/pu6mk5t5/) to reproduce the problem I'm trying to solve. If you hover over the first series after they diverge you can see that the second series, left in gray, is still drawn in front of it, and obscuring it.

How can I modify this sample code to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It worked for me when i changed:

```
function mouseOverCallback(event, series) {
  series.graph.attr('stroke', 'steelblue')
  series.graph.toFront()
}
```

to

```
function mouseOverCallback(event, series) {
  series.graph.attr('stroke', 'steelblue')
  series.group.toFront();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try simply updating the `zIndex` of the series upon `mouseOver` and `mouseOut`.

For example ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pu6mk5t5/7/)):

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        stickyTracking: false,
        events: {
            mouseOver: function (e) {
                e.target.update({ zIndex: 1000 });
                mouseOverCallback(e, this)
            },
            mouseOut: function (e) {
                e.target.update({ zIndex: undefined });
                mouseOutCallback(e, this)
            }
        }
    }
}
```